# Is there a PPA with a Wayland build I can use?

Tags: ppa, build, wayland

It seems like Wayland is coming to Ubuntu in the distant future. Being the curious type, I thought I would give it a try. I was going to build it myself, but wanted to save myself the trouble if there was a PPA somewhere I could use instead.

Is there a PPA anywhere I can use to try out Wayland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be the closest you're gonna get.
Again, sounds like its not currently far enough to be useful to build.

http://wayland.freedesktop.org/building.html

Comment: That's what I'm using to build.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think there is a ppa at this point. It would also not be very beneficial right now. What I gather from the information, I have seen so far, wayland does not yet have enough feature implemented that it could be just plugged into an Ubuntu or Kubuntu Desktop.

Hence, currently it is more something for developers to test out, who probably have no problems to just build the tarball, or clone a branch directly from the git repository.

Answer (score 5):

I just found this: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa
Anyway, don't know how to use it =P